# How can I make all users appear to have the same IP address?

Tags: http, proxy, ip-address, lamp

I work on a web app on a LAMP stack. Without going into too much detail, users of our site sign in to their account and are given URLs to visit. These URLs could be anywhere publicly accessible on the web.

Some of the URLs we want our users to visit might be restricted by IP address. I can tell the owners of those sites what IPs they should give access to. I would like to be able to give any users I select the ability to access those URLs but I can't guarantee what their personal IP address will be.

Is there an easy way, perhaps using some kind of proxy service, that I could get users to all appear to come from the same IP?

Comment: Not without opening a humongous security hole in your authentication, no. Why not a traditional authentication system?

Comment: How would this open a security hole in my authentication?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood, are you authenticating by IP, by user/password or key, or both? If both, why?

Comment: My web app authenticates by user/password. Once users have logged in, I want them to visit an external site I don't control that is restricted by IP. I can choose an IP range to be white-listed.

Comment: I'd probably use an sshtunnel + proxy, using the ssh-tunnel as authentification, or just a proxy if security isn't all that important. I don't have much experience setting those up though :(

What kind of data are on the links? Can you fetch the page by cURL?